# concatenate column values pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have a dateframe1 of values and i want to transform it into a new dataframe2 by concatenating values of columns in the original dataframe1 i.e

```
dataframe1
ProductName  Value otherValue
Product1      2     5
Product2      3     2
Product1      1     5
Product3      4     7
Product3      5     7
Product1      5     5
Product2      9     2

dataframe2
ProductName  Value     otherValue
Product1      2 1 5       5
Product2      3 9         2
Product3      4 5         7
```

Answer (score 2):

You could groupby `ProductName` and aggregate using `' '.join` on `Value` and `first` on `otherValue`:

```
result = df.assign().groupby('ProductName', as_index=False).agg({ 'Value' : lambda x : ' '.join(map(str, x)), 'otherValue' : 'first' } )

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  ProductName  Value  otherValue
0    Product1  2 1 5           5
1    Product2    3 9           2
2    Product3    4 5           7
```

Note that this solution assumes the column Value is not a string, otherwise you can use `' '.join` directly

Comment: Nice expansion of the `.agg` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this in two lines. first we need to turn the column `Value` into strings so we can perform join and operations and the second are all the operations to return the desired output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'ProductName':['Product1','Product2','Product1','Product3','Product3','Product1','Product2'],'Value':[2,3,1,4,5,5,9],'otherValue':[5,2,5,7,7,5,2]})
df['Value'] = df['Value'].astype(str)
df = df.merge(df.groupby('ProductName',as_index=True)['Value'].apply(' '.join).reset_index(),how='left',left_on='ProductName',right_on='ProductName').drop('Value_x',axis=1).drop_duplicates().rename(columns={'Value_y':'Value'})
```

print(df)
Output:

```
  ProductName  otherValue   Value
0    Product1           5   2 1 5
1    Product2           2     3 9
3    Product3           7     4 5
```